# Converting prefix expressions to infix

Tags: c, stack

Here is my new working code. Man, working with strings in C is tedious  and annoying. I had built the algorithm in short time, took hours figuring how to implement it properly in C. Tell me if there are more bugs or if some improvement is possible.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct node{
  char data[100];
  struct node *next;
}SNode;

typedef struct{
 int count;
 SNode *top;
}stack;

int isEmpty(stack *s){
  return (s->count==0);
 }

void push(stack *s,char x[]){
  SNode *temp = (SNode *)malloc(sizeof(SNode));
  strcpy(temp->data,x);
  temp->next = s->top;
  s->top=temp;
  s->count++;
  }

char * pop(stack *s){
     if(isEmpty(s)){
      return "-1";

     }
    SNode *temp = s->top;
    s->top = temp->next;
    static char a[10];
    strcpy(a,temp->data);
    free(temp);
    s->count--;
    return a;
  }


 int main(){
    stack *s = (stack *)malloc(sizeof(stack));
    s->count = 0;
    char a[100];
    printf("Enter prefix expression: ");
    gets(a);
    int i;
    for(i=strlen(a)-1;i>=0;i--){
    if(a[i]=='+'||a[i]=='-'||a[i]=='*'||a[i]=='/'){
       char s1[10], s2[10];
       strcpy(s1,pop(s));
       strcpy(s2, pop(s));
       char b1[10] ="(",b2[10]=")";
       strcat(b1,s1);
       char t[2]="\0";
       t[0]=a[i];
       strcat(b1,t);
       strcat(b1,s2);
       strcat(b1,b2);
       push(s,b1);
      }
     else if(isalpha(a[i])){
         char t[2] = "\0";
          t[0] = a[i];
          push(s,t);
     }
    }
    char *infix = pop(s);
    printf("Infix expression: %s",infix);
    return 0; 
     }
```

Comment: Not so fast ;-) I goes like that: You first write a title that states what your code does, instead of crying for help, then you write a nice description and explain what and how (perhaps even why) you did in your code.

Comment: You defintely have a bug in your conversion `*+ab+cd` should be `(a+b)*(c+d)` and not `a + b * c + d`

Comment: @HaraldScheirich no it is not a bug. you gave the input wrong. the correct input would be *(+ab)(+cd)

Comment: @Gameatro i disagree, look up a few references, `*+ab+cd` is equivalent to `mult(add(a,b),add(c,d))` which comes out to `(a + b) * (c + d)`. Prefix notation does not utilize parentheses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation

Comment: Whatever book you are reading for learning C, throw it away. It is too old. No sensible book recommends `gets` for anything.

Comment: @RolandIllig i know that. but there is not other easy way to get string input in c.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please don't change or add to the code in your question after you have received answers. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

### `malloc()`

In general, `malloc` may fail, and will return `NULL` when that happens, you should deal with that.

The result of `malloc` does not have to be cast to the target type, additionally it is usually safer to use the target variable in the `sizeof` expression.

```
stack *s = malloc(sizeof *s); 
if (s == NULL) { // deal with it}
```

### `gets()`

You have a buffer that is 100 chars wide, the long-deprecated `gets()` will just write over the end of the buffer, you should try and use [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) e.g `fgets(buffer, 100, stdin)` or alternatively [`gets_s()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) if your compiler supports C11's optional Annex K.

### Editing the string in place

Meaning changing the characters in the string without extra memory allocation. You're changing the string in place, this probably makes things much more complicated than they need to be. Using an input and an output string would clear things up. Using the pointer into the string rather than the string index might make things a little bit more readable as well. I don't think I would choose to edit the string in place unless I was forced to do it. Not shifting the string also makes it easier to visualize what's going on as you only have to move the index forward.

### Accessing the string via an index

With `char* buffer`, `buffer[i]` and `*buffer` are equivalent; I'd probably trend more towards using the string pointer rather than the index, that might be a matter of taste.

### Naming consistency

You have the `node` struct typedefed as `SNode` and the stack just typedefed as `stack`. It's easy to spot when someone is inconsistent, no matter if I agree with the style or not. Here there are two ways of how you define the struct and two ways (one capitalized, and the other not) of writing the typedef; stick to one way.

### `pop()`

Popping an empty stack is a bug in most cases, if not you probably should treat it like a bug and assert on the empty stack. Returning `\0` hides the fact that you tried to call pop on the empty stack making it harder to track down the bug

### Warnings

`isalpha()` is defined in `<ctype.h>` which is not included

### Bug

`*+ab+cd` is parsed as `a + b * c + d` and given operator precedence that is incorrect - the result should be `(a + b) * (c + d)`.

Comment: i  m working on the bug. for malloc, it wont fail unless ur ram is full.

Comment: well i worked out logic for the code to work the way you said. but i am having diff implementing it in c. how do i return an array in c. that is required for pop function. to return a string.

Comment: `gets_s()` is Visual Studio/Windows specific, a more common replacement is `fgets()` (from the POSIX standard).

Comment: @Gameatro You return a string by a pointer, to create a new string dynamically you will have to malloc it

Comment: @MartinR I amended the `gets()` section

Comment: But fgets() doesn't seem good. It requires string size as parameter. But here string size can be anything.

Comment: Of that malloc. I have instead used static pointer. So it it retains value outside function as well.

Comment: i changed my input method. take a look. i am using  scanf("%[^\n]s",a);

Comment: @Gameatro one of the skills to learn as a programmer is reading documentation, `scanf` doesn't solve the problem, it has the same problem as `gets`, if the string read is longer than the space provided it _will_ write over the end of your buffer. `fgets()` `gets_s()` solve this problem by limiting the number of characters they will read at the maximum. It doesn't mean that you need to know the size of string read. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets

Comment: @Harald - `scanf` *can* be used safely, but it's up to the programmer to remember to specify a field width between `%` and `s`.  But it's much less helpful, as its return value doesn't tell you what you need to know.

Comment: Martin - `fgets()` is Standard C (not just POSIX).

Answer (score 1):

Since your code relies on a max length of 100 you can reduce many code for your stack by using a simple array. A test for stack overflow must be added.

```
typedef struct {
    char *data[20];
    char **top;
} Stack;

int main() {
  Stack stack;
  stack.top = stack.data;
  ......

  // if you like..
  for(i=0; i<sizeof(stack.data)/sizeof(*stack.data); i++)
    if(stack.data[i]!=null) free(stack.data[i])
}

void push(Stack *s, char *t) {
    if(*s->top==null)
        *s->top = malloc(100);
    strcpy(*s->top, t);
    s->top++;
}
char *pop(Stack *s) {
    if(s->top > s->data) {
        s->top--;
        return *s->top;
    }
    return null;
}
```